# How properly to migrate bhyve vm to another host?

Tags: freebsd

I am stuck here and can not find more information about it.

Copying the snapshot/backup of the VM to another host:

```
zfs send disk/vmName | pv | ssh hostname "zfs recv diskDest/newVmName"
```

And then what? I tried to create it with:

```
vm create newVmName
```

But it seems that's not the way, because it says that the dataset already exist.

Comment: Moving the `zfs` dataset is nearly the **last** step in the process.  Can you please [edit] your question to show what steps you went through on the new host, prior to transfering the dataset, so that readers will know whether you have properly configured the new host to run `bhyve` VMs.

Comment: @JimL. Yes, let me test your recommendation and I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that needs to be done is to configure the new host to run `bhyve`.  That is covered in [Section 22.6 of the FreeBSD Handbook](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/virtualization/#virtualization-host-bhyve).

Next, I would recommend installing [Matt Churchyard's `vm-bhyve` package](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vm&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports):

```
# pkg install vm-bhyve
```

and its requisite configuration.  Before you try to migrate your existing VM, go through all the setup steps in the `vm` manpage to ensure that your new machine is set up correctly.  I'd recommend that you even go so far as to create and test  a VM on the new host, just to ensure that the new host is configured correctly.  I think you'll find it a frustrating exercise to try and migrate an existing VM to a `bhyve` instance that is not properly set up on the new host.  Do yourself a favor and lay a solid foundation by testing your new `bhyve` installation thoroughly before you try to migrate a VM onto it.

Additionally, let's not modify the VM name while transfering it.  Once you have it working on the new host, renaming the VM is as simple as `vm rename vmName newVmName`.

Once you have `bhyve` and `vm` working, then you should be able to stop your VM on the old host, snapshot it, and transfer that snapshot to the new host.  To avoid complications, we'll preserve the name of the filesystem, and we will not (yet) mount the filesystem on the new host:

On `oldhost`:

```
# vm stop vmName
# zfs snap disk/vmName@xfer
# zfs send disk/vmName@xfer | pv -Wbfart | \
    ssh newhost "zfs recv -Fuv diskDest/vmName"
```

On `newhost`, set the mountpoint of the new filesystem to be the same basename as it was on the old host.  So if the old host's VM was mounted at `/foobar/vmName`, and you're moving  to directory `/bhyve/` on the new host, the new VM filesystem needs to be mounted at `/bhyve/vmName`.  Once the mountpoint has been set, the new filesystem can be mounted on `newhost`:

```
# zfs set mountpoint=/bhyve/vmName diskDest/vmName
# zfs mount diskDest/vmName
```

I recommend you leverage the heirarchical nature of ZFS and create a parent filesystem `diskDest/bhyve` mounted at `/bhyve` and create a separate child filesystem for each VM, such as `diskDest/bhyve/vmName`, but that's up to you.

At this point, the migrated VM should show up in the output of `vm list` and you can start it and troubleshoot any remaining start-up issues that appear on `stderr` or in `/bhyve/vmName/vm-bhyve.log`.

Comment: Did not work on my systems. The approach I did is - after sending the snap, I created a VM and changed the disk to point the snapshop destionation. I understood that zfs send/recv is kind of sending the disk itself.

Comment: @Baequirahael That is not what I suggested.

Comment: the problem is the new disk is a block device and the old one is dataset. If both of them are the same, I think this solution is going to work.

Comment: @Baequirahael If at all possible, keep the new host's VM on a ZFS filesystem also.  `vm-bhyve` integrates nicely with ZFS for snapshotting, cloning and renaming VM filesystems.  If you have further difficulties, please [edit] your question to describe more thoroughly what you have done, and what specific errors you are encountering.

Comment: Man, thank you! I successfully moved my VM to another host using your instructions. Only I had a VM with ZVOL, so I changed your commands a bit:
`zfs snap -r zroot/vm/myvm@xfer` then `zfs send -R zroot/vm/myvm@xfer | pv -Wbfart | ssh root@192.168.1.xx "zfs recv -Fuv zroot/vm/myvm"`

Comment: After that I just needed to mount the VM on the new host: `zfs mount zroot/vm/myvm`. And then the VM started up right away.